# Php Check Specific Format for String

Tags: php, string

I need to check format of all string insert.

The format must be word1-word2-number. For example (pippo-pippo-12122018)

How to check if string has this format or not?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious would be to use regex, but since the string is easily parsed and fairly simple to check I suggest using a more conventional method.
This loops the parts of the string and checks if the first two parts is string and the second is a number.

```
$str = "pippo-pippo-12122018";
$arr = explode("-", $str);

$valid = true;
if(count($arr) >3) $valid = false;
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    if($key<2){
        if(!is_string($val)) $valid = false;
    }else{
        if(!is_numeric($val)) $valid = false;
    }
}

var_export($valid);
```

https://3v4l.org/kfZvn